# Google Sheets Scripting Errors

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheets

I am having a problem with a Google Sheets issue.  I scripted this:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onFormSubmit()
{
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var email_address = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow()
var lastColumn=sheet.getLastColumn()
var entries=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastColumn)
for(var i=1; i<=lastColumn; i++)
{
var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).getValues()
if(cell==0)
{
var previousCell=sheet.getRange((lastRow-1),i).getValues()
sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).setValues(previousCell)
}
}
}
```

Yet I get an error that it does not exist with the trigger I created

> 6/23/19 4:48 PM
>
> myFunction
>
> Script function not found: myFunction
>
> formSubmit
>
> 6/23/19 4:48 PM.

I have deleted and recreated+edited the code multiple times and deleted and recreated the trigger multiple times and to no avail.

I got my javascript friends to help and they believe it is something wrong with the software, which is why I posted here.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Javascript is off-topic here.  Our programming site, Stack Overflow, would be the place for that.  Google Sheets is off-topic here, on topic at the Web Apps site.  I voted to migrate this to Web Apps, but if it is really a Javascript question, you might want to delete this post and repost on SO, or flag a moderator and ask them to migrate it for you.

Comment: my apologies!!! will switch now!!1 Im sooo sorry!